# How to do lighthouse audit for a PWA which needs authentication

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I am trying to do a lighthouse audit of my angular . My app uses `jwt` based authentication and I store the token in the `localStorage`.

I first login through the app and then start the lighthouse audit. But when the audit run starts the session is completely lost and the report is created based on the login page.

I have tried to open the browser using

`ng serve --open`

and then running lighthouse audit but, it still didn't worked

How to do a lighthouse audit after authentication ?

Comment: Are you use the Lighthouse Chrome extension or the Lighthouse CLI?

Comment: @WillTaylor i am using Lighthose Chrome extension

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncheck `Clear storage`:

[image: Lighthouse clear storage]

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/authenticated-pages.md